# How to Count Number of divs within another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I saw that one can calculate the number of divs by id with the following code:

```
$('div[id^=d]').length
```

however I want to calculate the number of divs inside a in specific , example below

```
<div class="DAD"> 
  <DIV CLASS="The DIV BE TOLD"></DIV>
  <DIV CLASS="The DIV BE TOLD"></DIV>
  <DIV CLASS="The DIV BE TOLD"></DIV>
  <DIV CLASS="The DIV BE TOLD"></DIV>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('div.DAD  div').length` would do it.

Or

`$('div.DAD div.The.DIV.BE.TOLD').length`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/y21drdcj/)**

See: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery allows you to use the syntax of CSS selectors (have a look [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)):

```
$('div.DAD div').length
```

should give the answer you're looking for